Finding the UUID of a biosphere3 flow in Brightway2
Is there a Brightway method to retrieve the UUID of a specific biosphere3 flow? My desired biosphere flow is:
'Water, lake' (cubic meter, None, ('natural resource', 'in water'))

Using the name fails to link my custom LCIA method to the flow.

here is the simplest way to do it.
In [1]: import bw2data as bd

In [2]: bd.projects.set_current('yourProject')

In [3]: bio = bd.Database('biosphere3')
# search for water
In [4]: water = bio.search('Water, lake')
# check the returned list
In [5]: water
Out[5]: ['Water, lake' (cubic meter, None, ('natural resource', 'in water'))]
# select the one you want by index
In [6]: water = water[0]
# get the code
In [7]: water['code']
Out[7]: '1acb026e-9de6-48fe-9e0d-be4d24125bbc'
# for more information about the flow
In [8]: water.__dict__
Out[8]: 
{'_document': <ActivityDataset: 919>,
 '_data': {'categories': ('natural resource', 'in water'),
  'code': '1acb026e-9de6-48fe-9e0d-be4d24125bbc',
  'CAS number': '007732-18-5',
  'synonyms': ['oxidane'],
  'name': 'Water, lake',
  'database': 'biosphere3',
  'unit': 'cubic meter',
  'type': 'natural resource',
  'id': 919}}



If you do you should get a list of elementary flows with only one entry
water_list = bd.Database('biosphere3').search('Water, lake') 
water = water_list[0]

alternatively
water = bd.Database('biosphere3').get(name='Water, lake')

once you have the water you can create your own method for which you'd need a list of tuples e.g.
my_cfs = [(water.key,cf1),]

